# How I can switch to secondary node from primary

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I'm using a replicaset with 3 nodes. Node primary with name n1 and port 27018, secondaries n2 port 27019 and n3 por 27020.

I would like to switch to any secondady node from primary. I've tried with **mongo -host n2 -port 27019** but not work for me returns:
"uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:12"

There is another way to do it? I looked in the documentation but I didn't found nothing

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you are running this command in mongo shell rather than a command terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the same command from the CLI instead of the Mongo Shell. Also consider to use the double dash when specify the full name options, like above:

```
mongo --host n2 --port 27019
```

In this way you will be able to accesso in read-only mode the data. In order to navigate dbs you will need to run the following command first:

```
rs.secondaryOk()
```

Instead, if your needings are to switch the primary node to the "n2" node, you will need to run the following queries in your primary:

```
cfg = rs.config()
cfg.members[1].priority = 10 \\ "set a value higher than the primary node"
rs.reconfig(cfg)
rs.stepDown()
```

In this way you will set the election priority and running the step down command will force the n2 node to become primary

Answer (score 1):

- In command terminal you can try.

```html
mongo "mongodb://host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/myDB?replicaSet=myRS"
```

or

- In the shell, you can first open a mongo session without connecting to mongo replicaset

```html
mongo --nodb
```

- in mongo shell you can connect to a replicaset.

```html
conn = new Mongo("myRS/host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017")

db = conn.getDB("myDB")
```